# Media Manager Captions and BluePrinting

Tags: blueprint, media-manager

I understand that in Media Manager we can caption a video asset in multiple languages and then set its Language in a Distribution.

With the Media Manager Connector, how do we get the appropriate caption language in publication with translated content? For example, the Hindi language publication should present the Hindi translated caption from a Video distribution (using the HTML 5 Player, for example).

I understand Media Manager has its own way of handling translation, but I'm not sure if we need multiple Distributions or if there's a way to get the right caption against a single Distribution (by query string parameter)?

Answer (score 5):

The Distribution URL supports a query string parameter, "`sl`", which specifies what subtitles to show (presumably if available). See the [Online Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDLMediaManager29-v2/GUID-D02914DA-1120-41CB-936E-A6680C161101)

This value could be held in Publication Metadata or other configuration and appended onto the Distribution URL as appropriate by templating.

This could also work for Voice-overs and Backslides.

Comment: Ah, nice. So no localization or extra Distributions needed. Maybe I should ask @BartKoopman if he has that TBB already. ;-)

Comment: @AlvinReyes I'm still waiting for a release of SDL Web where you can set a language for a Publication. Because using Publication metadata means everybody can use a different field name, although for DXA I guess we could do it (language is set in a configuration Component, so it has a default location there).

Comment: That's on my wishlist too. Quote: "For example, if all customers used certain Publication Metadata fields with the same options (e.g. language codes...)... it would make sense to add "language code" as a Publication product feature, rather than an implementation option." ;-) http://www.createandbreak.net/2015/06/that-should-be-in-product.html